# SendMessage to minimized window

Tags: vb.net, sendmessage

I'm trying to click a button in a minimised application, I use this code

```
Private Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN = &H201
Private Const WM_LBUTTONUP = &H202
Dim ParenthWnd As New IntPtr(0)
Dim hWnd As New IntPtr(0)
ParenthWnd = FindWindow(Nothing, "Title of application")

If ParenthWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
    Debug.WriteLine(""Title of application" is not running")
Else
    hWnd = FindWindowEx(ParenthWnd, hWnd, "Button", "Login")
    If hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        Debug.WriteLine(""Title of application" doesn't have a 'Login' button, how strange!")
    Else
        Debug.WriteLine(""Title of application" Window: " & ParenthWnd.ToString())
        Debug.WriteLine("Button Control: " & hWnd.ToString())
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1, 0)
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, 0)

    End If
End If
```

I get a real result in the debug window:

```
"title of window" Window: 2492018
Button Control: 1836764
```

But it still only "marks" the button and doesn't click it, anyone know what I should change?

Answer (score 0):

I think some windows apps freezing the gui thread if it is minimized. I know that sendMessage and postMessage are able to send keys to windows which are not focused or still in the background. 
So you need to make a workaround like

http://sim0n.wordpress.com/2009/03/27/vbnet-q-sending-mouseclickskeystrokes-into-minimized-window/

Comment: I followed that tutorial but that wasn't the problem, valter solved it for me, thanks for the anticiptation though!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SendMessage(hWnd, &HF5, New IntPtr(0), New IntPtr(0))
```

where `hWnd` is the button handle and BM_CLICK = 0x00F5.

valter